# Execution time in CLI and included files

Tags: php, command-line-interface, execution-time

I'm trying to run php script from CLI like this:

> php -q /var/www/script.php

As i know if you run it from CLI there is no max_execution_time, but if i use functions from required/included files, after 5-10 minutes i have fatal error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in
>   /var/www/include.php on line 10

So max_execution_time does not apply to included files?
It is possible to avoid this without adding set_time_limit(0) in every included file?

Comment: what's in `/var/www/include.php on line 10`?

Comment: _mysqli_query("SELECT_ etc.

Comment: `set_time_limit(60)` in /var/www/include.php or other previously included files as I suggested in my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps one of the included files set (for whatever reason) a `set_time_limit(60)`? If that's the case, you could probably work around it by calling `set_time_limit(0)` after every include in your `PHP` CLI script... Or edit the files contaning the `set_time_limit(60)`, which might of course lead to unwanted side effects...

Comment: Yep, somewhere in included files i found it. Shame on me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
php -d max_execution_time=5 script.php
```